# Exp-resso store email template testing

Tags: expresso-store

Is there a way to re-test the emails generated during the payment process?
Currently I have to create an order and go through all the checkout steps, payment and wait for a new email, for every change I make.
This is extremely long winded.
Is there an easier way to test the email templates against an existing order?

Comment: Just a thought, maybe dummy up your template variables and use litmus or some other service to test your actual code then once happy, replace your dummy code with system vars

Comment: What would be a lot better is if the orders section in the backend had a link to resend the confirmation email. Useful for testing and for end users.

Comment: Changing their status would indicate new emails are sent as per the docs: https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/control_panel_orders.html#order_actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not overly intuitive but hey, it works...

Changing their status would indicate new emails are sent as per the docs: https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/control_panel_orders.html#order_actions